# Error about initializing database - entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

Getting error saving the object in the database stage .I'm waiting for a suggestion for a solution from those who have information on the subject.

I checked my connection strings actually dont have much idea to try.

```
    public void SaveNew(Person p)
    {
        using (var context = new FeatureContext())
        {
            context.People.Add(p);// error line
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

exception

```
 System.Data.DataException: 'An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.'
 SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\ertug.dilek\source\repos\AddFeatures\WebApplication1\App_Data\AddFeatures.Model.FeatureContext.mdf' 
 as database 'AddFeatures.Model.FeatureContext'.
```

Comment: can you paste your connection string ?

Comment: Your connection string should look something like this:Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Rich\\source\\repos\\Database_MDF\\Database_MDF\\App_Data\\MusicLibrary.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: It might be a dumb question, but you do have an SQL Server (Express) instance installed on your machine, yes?

Comment: remove the Initial Catalog portion from your connection string if you also use AttachDBFilename.

Comment: @StevePy I created a project and used a database previously

Comment: @OuSs Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AddFeatures.Model.FeatureContext;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: @user10728126 i sent comment with connection string u can check also